# py request session persistence to redis

Tags: python, redis, python-requests

I am trying to store py request sessions in redis for a particular id and service. so for a particular id and service there should be only one py-request-session stored in redis.

```
def __init__(self, data, method):
    self.data = data
    self.method = method

def http_call(self):

    session = self._load(self.data['id'], self.data['service'])

    handler = getattr(self, self.method.lower())
    resp = handler(session=session, data=params, options=self.optional_params)

    self._store(self.data['id'], self.data['service'], session)

    return resp

def post(self, session=None, data=None, json=None, options=None):
    req = session or requests
    return req_obj.post(self.target, data=data, json=json, **options)

def get(self, session=None, data=None, options=None):
    request = session or requests
    return request.get(self.target, params=data, **options)

@staticmethod
def _load(id=None, service=None):
    session = REDIS.get('{}_{}'.format(id, service))

    if session is None:
        session = requests.session()
    else:
        session = pickle.loads(session)

    return session

@staticmethod
def _store(id=None, service=None, session=None):
    return REDIS.set('{}_{}'.format(id, service), pickle.dumps(session))
```

The above is a sample code and http_call api can be called by multiple threads. One issue i see with the above code is that if multiple threads for a particular id and service execute simultaneously, there is a possibility of concurrent _load() calls for the same (id & service) with redis returning   None for all those threads resulting in all threads creating new session for the same id & service . I want to know what would be the best way to handle this. I would like to avoid having locks as much as possible.